# Workaround for missing UIBarButtonItem's TouchUp event

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

using a UIButton allows me to catch TouchUpInside and TouchUpOutside events to know when the user releases the button with his finger.

UIBarButtonItem doesn't have any events/notifications to be used in this manner.

Does anyone know a nice workaround to know when a UIBarButtonItem is physically released?
Is there a way to use an UIButton in a UIToolBar with the **same "design"** and behavior like a UIBarButtonItem?

Thanks!

Comment: did you have any luck with this? i'm stuck on the same thing

Answer (score 1):

```
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
....


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  barButton.action = @selector(onBarButtonTap);

....

- (IBAction)onBarButtonTap
{
  NSLog( @"BarButton Taped" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UIToolbar you can drag a UIButton into the bar. It will get embedded inside a UIBarButtonItem and you can link actions to the embedded UIButton